# C++ - Strange time measurements with Visual Studio

Tags: c++11

I tried to calculate the performance of some low-level assembly code produced by the compiler. However, at some moment I got strange results which I don't understand. So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    std::srand(time(NULL));
    constexpr unsigned vectorSize = 1000u;
    constexpr unsigned loopCount = 1000000u;
    std::vector<int> vec1(vectorSize);
    std::vector<int> vec2(vectorSize);
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vectorSize; ++i)
    {
        vec1[i] = std::rand();
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vectorSize; ++i)
    {
        vec2[i] = std::rand();
    }

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> end;
    long long ms;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned j = 0u; j < loopCount; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec2[i] = vec1[i];
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Evaluation took: " << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned j = 0u; j < loopCount; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec2[i] = vec1[i];
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Evaluation took: " << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned j = 0u; j < loopCount; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec2[i] = vec1[i];
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Evaluation took: " << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned j = 0u; j < loopCount; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec2[i] = vec1[i];
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Evaluation took: " << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned j = 0u; j < loopCount; ++j)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0u; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        {
            vec2[i] = vec1[i];
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Evaluation took: " << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "Press enter to exit..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Main "work" in this program is done in the loop where elements of vector vec1 are simply assigned to vector vec2. The inner for loop condition is intended to don't allow compiler for SIMD optimization. I repeated the code 5 times by copying it, so I expected to get more or less the same time measurement for every single copy. However, results are different:

> Evaluation took: 425 ms
>   Evaluation took: 694 ms
>   Evaluation took: 462 ms
>   Evaluation took: 441 ms
>   Evaluation took: 710 ms
>   Press enter to exit...

That's how it looks after building with Visual Studio 2015 in Release mode. Surprisingly, with GCC calculated times are very similar, but with Visual I got this strange pattern every single time and it's always the same.

So I want to ask if my code is somehow corrupted, am I missing something? Or maybe this is just compiler strange behavior?
It's kind of important to get right time measurement in any kind of benchmarking so I don't want to make mistake right from the start.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/EZUV41573)

Comment: So it look's like strange compiler behaviour.